# Android Studio - ListView Error (Unfortunately Stopped Working)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android development and learning listview from WSCube. I have seen several other youtube videos also but cannot find the solution to it. Please check and advise.

I have attached all the codes than i have worked on my system through watching from the videos of WsCube youtube channel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsxqI.png)

#### **Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ListView"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_Main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.listview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> arrNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        listView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrNames.add("Daniel01");
        arrNames.add("Daniel02");
        arrNames.add("Daniel03");
        arrNames.add("Daniel04");
        arrNames.add("Daniel05");
        arrNames.add("Daniel06");
        arrNames.add("Daniel07");
        arrNames.add("Daniel08");
        arrNames.add("Daniel09");
        arrNames.add("Daniel10");
        arrNames.add("Daniel11");
        arrNames.add("Daniel12");
        arrNames.add("Daniel13");
        arrNames.add("Daniel14");
        arrNames.add("Daniel15");
        arrNames.add("Daniel16");
        arrNames.add("Daniel17");
        arrNames.add("Daniel18");
        arrNames.add("Daniel19");
        arrNames.add("Daniel20");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrNames);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: ```listView.findViewById(R.id.listView);``` You should assign your ```listView``` instead of calling function.

Comment: thanks.... i also changed getApplicationContext() to MainActivity.this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake here.

```java
listView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

That is wrong. Because you use a dot `.` between `listView` and `findViewById(R.id.listView);`.

You need to initialize the `listView` variable. You can do that with equal to `=` See the example I gave here.

#### Solution

```java
listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
```